# How to change the DateTime format in a JQuery view of a C#\.NET web application?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am working on a C#.NET web application and I have the following doubt:

I have a model object that contains the following **DateTime** field:

```
public System.DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
```

This field value is shown into a view implemented using **JQuery Mobile**, in this way (so the user can edit this value):

```
<div class="ui-field-contain">
    <label for="LastUpdated">Date:</label>
    <input name="LastUpdated" id="LastUpdated" style="margin-bottom:15px;" value="@Model.LastUpdated" type="date">
</div>
```

Now my problem is that, into the input, tag the printed value is a data having the following format: **09/07/2014 11:09:08** (day/month/year time)

What can I to do to print a data that don't show the time? (having this formt: **09/07/2014**)

Can I do it using Jquery or have I to do it in C#?

Tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the method toShortDate:

```
value="@Model.LastUpdated.ToShortDateString()"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `value="@Model.LastUpdated.ToString("MM/dd/yy")"`